# Como transformar esse texto em um array com nome e descrição?

Tags: php

Eu tenho um ficheiro .txt. Ele tem o nome das imagens e a descrição sobre elas. Então eu queria fazer do seguinte modo:

```
nome:descrição
imagem1.jpg:"descrição exemplo 1";
```

Eu sei como ler o ficheiro php. Agora queria separar a informação, mas não sei que função em [php](/questions/tagged/php) pode fazer isso, de modo a ter `$nome` e `$descrição` em variáveis diferentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

Primeiro abra o conteúdo do texto e salve numa variável:

```
$string = file_get_contents('arquivo.txt');
```

Em seguida vamos criar um array com cada linha do arquivo.

```
$array = array_filter(explode("\n", $string));
```

Agora vamos mapear o `array` para que ele transforme a divisão de `:` em um `array` de 2 items. Em seguida, vamos usar `array_combine` para combinar chaves com os dois valores (as chaves serão "nome" e "descrição")

```
$callback = function ($value) {
     return array_combine(array('nome', 'descricao'), explode(":", $value, 2));
};

$array = array_map($callback, $array);
```

Por fim, podemos ver o resultado:

```
var_dump($array);
```

**Melhorias**

Ao invés de usar `file_get_contents` e em seguida um `explode` em `\n`, podemos evoluir nessa expressão usando a função `file`:

```
 $array = array_filter(file('arquivo.txt'));
```

Nesse caso, a função `file` já abre o arquivo, deixando cada linha em um elemento do `array`.

Para percorrer os valores, basta usar o `foreach`:

```
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       echo $value['descricao'];
       echo $value['nome'];
   }
```

Veja um exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/9VrcXF)

Comment: Como eu obtenho mesmo o valor?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes se ele está em um arquivo TXT, a linha com `file_get_contents` abre o arquivo desejado

Comment: http://pcrinteriores.com/ nao esta a dar

Comment: Manda o TXT pra eu ver

Comment: Art Deco.jpg:Descrição teste!
Touro.jpg:Descrição teste!2

Comment: http://pcrinteriores.com/img/portfolio/imagens.txt

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes mas cadê o cabecalho? Na pergunta você colocou cabecalho... Se quiser eu altero a resposta

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes agora sim, estava completamente diferente do que eu pensei

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55200/discussion-between-amadeu-antunes-and-wallace-maxters).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `file()`:

```
$arquivo = file('arquivo.txt');

foreach($arquivo as $index => $linha){

    list($info[$index]['imagem'], $info[$index]['descricao']) = explode(':', trim($linha));

}
```

Dessa forma irá resultar em:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["imagem"]=>
    string(12) "Art Deco.jpg"
    ["descricao"]=>
    string(20) "Descrição teste!"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["imagem"]=>
    string(9) "Touro.jpg"
    ["descricao"]=>
    string(19) "Descrição teste!2"
  }
}
```

Assim poderá manipular a array como quiser, não está claro como ou quais são os objetivos após ler os dados, caso queira exibi-los pode fazer:

```
foreach($arquivo as $linha){

    list($imagem, $descricao) = explode(':', trim($linha));

    echo '<img src="'.$imagem.'" />';
    echo '<p>'.$descricao.'</p>';

}
```

Comment: A ideia do `list($image, $descricao)` é ótima, nem precisa alocar os valores.