# Como ler arquivo txt e montar array php?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de ler um arquivo .txt e montar um array PHP com cada linha do arquivo .txt pra depois montar JSON se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

Quero que a exibição fique dessa maneira:

```
{
"empregados": [
    {
        "nome": "Jason Jones",
        "idade": 38,
        "sexo": "M"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Ada Pascalina",
        "idade": 35,
        "sexo": "F"
    },
    {
        "nome": "Delphino da Silva",
        "idade": 26,
        "sexo": "M"
    }
]
```

}

Este é meu código:

```
<?php $dadox = array();
$dado = fopen("new_2.txt", "r");



while (!feof ($dado)) {
//se extraio uma linha do arquivo e nao eh false
if ($linha = fgets($dado)){
$dadox[] = $linha;
}

$cpf = substr("$linha", 0, 11 );
$nome = substr("$linha", 11, 32 );
$end = substr("$linha", 43, 28 );
$com = substr("$linha", 75 , 8 );
$cidade = substr("$linha", 87 , 13 );
$uf = substr("$linha", 103 , 2 );


//fclose($arquivo);
header('Content-Type: application/json');


 $funcionario =
     array(
       'CPF'=>"$cpf",
        'Nome'=>"$nome",
        'Endereco'=>"$end",
         'Complemento'=>"$com",
         'Cidade'=>"$cidade",
          'UF'=>"$uf"

     );
     $dados = array(
       $funcionario
     );

    $dados_funcionario = array('funcionario' => $dados);

    $json_str = json_encode($dados_funcionario,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);



    echo "$json_str";
//var_dump($funcionario);
} ?>
```

Comment: Sim, muitas maneiras, mas todas dependem do formato do seu arquivo. Poderia [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar um exemplo e descrever qual é a saída desejada?

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189409/como-transformar-esse-texto-em-um-array-com-nome-e-descri%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Como ele está delimitado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi citado, existem N formas de resolver essa questão, abaixo vou apresentar uma supondo que os dados estão delimitados conforme seu exemplo.

**Esse seria seu new_2.txt**

```
12345678912primeiro nome do cliente        endereço 1                  comp 1  cidade 1     SP
12345678912segundo nome do cliente         endereço 2                  comp 2  cidade 2     MG
```

Segue como ficaria uma possível solução

```
<?php

$dadox['empregados'] = array();
$lines = file('new_2.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('#^(?<cpf>[0-9]{11})(?<nome>[^\n]{32})(?<end>[^\n]{28})(?<com>[^\n]{8})(?<cidade>[^\n]{13})(?<uf>[^\n]{2})#iu', trim($line), $arr)) {
        $dadox['empregados'][] = array(
            'cpf' => $arr['cpf'],
            'nome' => $arr['nome'],
            'end' => $arr['end'],
            'com' => $arr['com'],
            'cidade' => $arr['cidade'],
            'uf' => $arr['uf']
        );
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($dadox);
```

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o regex, pois você pode ver um exemplo do mesmo rodando aqui https://regex101.com/r/5TyRzk/1 e completamente detalhado.

Comment: Vlw mano! Exatamente isso que eu queria.